# How can I make a button light up if the right information is entered?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, calculator

I made a permutation and combination calculator. If the permutation | combination is selected, and the values are entered, the calculate button should light up. How can I do this without setting interval. My current code:

```
function checkCalc(){
 if(((permutation==true)||(combination==true))&&(document.getElementById('r').value.length>0)&&(document.getElementById('n').value.length>0)){
  calculate.style.backgroundColor="#ccccff";
  calculate.style.boxShadow="10px 10px 5px gray";
 }
 else{
  calculate.style.backgroundColor="gray";
 }
}

setInterval(checkCalc, 50);
```

If I remove the function(just leaving the if statement), it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call this function on keyup from the input.

I have made a demo:

```js
var permutation=true;
var combination=true;
var calculate= document.getElementById('calculate')
function checkCalc(){
 if(((permutation==true)||(combination==true))&&(document.getElementById('r').value.length>0)&&(document.getElementById('n').value.length>0)){
   calculate.style.backgroundColor="#ccccff";
   calculate.style.boxShadow="10px 10px 5px gray";
 }else{
   calculate.style.backgroundColor="gray";
 }
}
```

```html
<input type ="text" id ='r' onkeyup="checkCalc()">
<input type ="text" id ='n' onkeyup="checkCalc()">
<button id="calculate">Light</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are checking for the value anyway, you could set an event listener on `r` text field (I assume it is a text field?), which would be trigged once you type something:

```
document.getElementById('r').onkeydown=function(){
 if(((permutation==true)||(combination==true))&&(document.getElementById('r').value.length>0)&&(document.getElementById('n').value.length>0)){
  calculate.style.backgroundColor="#ccccff";
  calculate.style.boxShadow="10px 10px 5px gray";
 }
 else{
  calculate.style.backgroundColor="gray";
 }
}
```